# messages.getConversationMembers vk api python не выдаёт пользователей

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Ну вот такой код, ну вернее сказать отрезок кода

```
                    chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
                    print(vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=200000000 + chat_id , fields='profiles')
```

и он не работает как надо, тоесть не выдаёт список пользователей, а выдаёт

```
{'items': [{'member_id': -204434733}, {'member_id': 200000001}], 'count': 2, 'profiles': [{'first_name': 'DELETED', 'id'
: 200000001, 'last_name': '', 'deactivated': 'deleted'}], 'groups': [{'id': 204434733, 'name': 'БОТ - Гулять идём?', 'sc
reen_name': 'ddrx5', 'is_closed': 1, 'type': 'group', 'photo_50': 'https://vk.com/images/community_50.png', 'photo_100':
 'https://vk.com/images/community_100.png', 'photo_200': 'https://vk.com/images/community_200.png'}]}
```

как исправить чтобы вместо DELETED выдавалась нужная информация ?

Comment: ну вообще id200000001 действительно является удаленным профилем

Comment: в беседе нет не одного удалённого пользователя

Comment: я думаю проблема в fields, в том что я там указал и как но подтвердить эту версию я не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как исправить чтобы вместо DELETED выдавалась нужная информация ?

Функция возвращает `deleted` в том случае, если аккаунт удалён.

Цитата из вк:

> поле возвращается, если страница пользователя удалена или заблокирована, содержит значение deleted или banned. В этом случае опциональные поля не возвращаются.

---

> он не работает как надо, тоесть не выдаёт список пользователей

Он выдаёт вам ответ `JSON` формата с данными, иначе возникла бы ошибка.

Также заметил, что у вас в `print(vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=200000000 + chat_id , fields='profiles')` ключ  *`peer_id`* имеет значение `200000000 + chat_id`, может правильнее так: `2000000000 + chat_id`.

Comment: я могу скинуть скриншот и доказательства того что в чате нет удалённых пользователей

Comment: @Matthew я дополнил ответ, посмотрите. И да, если вы дизлайкнули, то не могли бы пояснить почему.

Comment: да секундочку пожалуйста и я всё объясню

Comment: Я дизлайкнул до того как вы дополнили ответ потому-что аккаунта удалённого в беседе нету, а вы пишите что такой ответ может выдавать только в случаи если аккаунт удалён. Вот док-ва: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/0P3PeC4ZFI17xw можете глянуть. НО благодаря вам, точнее вашему изменению я нашел ошибку в недостающем количестве нолей в peer_id https://disk.yandex.ru/i/ILQ5kyQ_tXSm-Q

Comment: Так что я прошу прощение за заранее поставленную отметку, и большое вам спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Metthew ничего страшного, главное разобрались)

Comment: Согласен с вами